# jQuery how to make this any faster or atleast release the select box when clicked?

Tags: jquery, html, custom-data-attribute

Am trying to make it possible to filter a list of divs...  And it kind of works, however, it is extremely slow and when you select an option in the select box, it does not release the select box until after it is finished filtering all of the elements.

The following is the code I am using:

```
(function($) {
    $("#tif-maincategories").change(function() {
        var currCat = $(this).val();
        if (currCat != "all")
        {
            var memberCount = $("div.tif-member-listing").length;

            for (x=0; x < memberCount - 1; x++)
            {
                var theCats = $("div.tif-member-listing").eq(x).attr("data-categories");
                var cats = theCats.split("|");
                if ($.inArray(currCat, cats) > -1)
                    $("div.tif-member-listing").eq(x).show({duration: "fast", queue: false});
                else
                    $("div.tif-member-listing").eq(x).hide({duration: "slow", queue: false});
            }
        }
        else
            $(".tif-member-listing").show({duration: "fast", queue: false});
    });
}(jQuery));
```

For some strange reason, using `$(this).data("categories")` does not work for trying to get the categories that relate to that option in the select box.  Since it gives me an undefined error when attempting to do this.  So, am using `.attr("data-categories")` instead.

But how to do this without the crazy amount of lag, when selecting something?

Comment: Is it possible to change the html structure too? or it's not possible to change html code? i think the problem is html structure that produce lots of work for JQuery section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the main issues you have is that every time you `change` the `select` element, you do a lot of stuff in the handler (the 'repeats', which Moshtaf alluded to in his answer) - some of which you only need to do once (and cache that...)

Here's a fiddle that demonstrates caching logic: http://jsfiddle.net/9us1zq7e/

Fiddle with CSS3 fading (suggested by Arun): http://jsfiddle.net/9us1zq7e/1/

And the updated JS, which caches your cats:

```
(function($) {
    var $tifColumn = $('.tif-column');

    var hash = {};

    // Cache cats
    $('div.tif-member-listing').each(function(idx, el) {
        var cats = $(this).data('categories');

        if (cats.toString().indexOf('|') !== -1) {
            cats = cats.split('|');
        } else {
            cats = [cats];
        }

        cats.forEach(function(obj) {
            if (!hash[obj]) {
                hash[obj] = [el];
            } else {
                hash[obj].push(el);
            }
        });
    });


    $('#tif-maincategories').change(function() {
        var currCat = $(this).val(),
            elArray;

        if (currCat !== 'all') {
            $tifColumn.addClass('filtered');

            // Reset
            $('.visible').removeClass('visible');

            elArray = hash[currCat];

            elArray.forEach(function(el) {
                $(el).addClass('visible');
            });

        } else {
            $tifColumn.removeClass('filtered');
        }
    });
}(jQuery));
```

To explain the JS a bit more - at the very start, we immediately cache the categories by iterating through each div with the `tif-member-listing` and then map the elements to the cat id. We reference the elements in an array since multiple elements can be associated with a category.

After, we bind the element with the `change` event, but we reference our map of elements (rather than looping through the DOM each time, which is slow...) and determine which elements need to be shown or hidden.

Hopefully this will help you improve your performance.

Comment: Wow, thanks.  This is perfect!  Definitely will try and follow caching in the future here!  Just did away with the animation since that seems problematic anyways.

Comment: I get tons of javascript errors on this:  `forEach`, apparently, that is not proper... `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined `

Comment: @SolomonClosson - Good point! I'm using `forEach` to iterate the arrays, but if you're required to support browsers that do not natively support `forEach` (less than IE9, for instance), then you could either shim it (add forEach to the `Array` prototype) or use a `for` loop. `forEach` is such a convenience, though! (and playing around with it without needing to worry about IE support...heaven!)

Comment: Thanks, I just used jQuery's `$.each()` on it and that seems to work just fine now.  Cheers :)

Answer (score 2):

This is your original code:

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/akbofevb/)

And this is optimized code:

```
(function($) {
    $("#tif-maincategories").change(function(e) {
        var currCat = $(this).val();
        if (currCat != "all"){
            $("div.tif-member-listing").each(function(e){
            $this = $(this);
            var theCats = $this.attr("data-categories");
            if (theCats.indexOf(currCat) > -1)
                $this.show({duration: "fast", queue: false});
            else
                $this.hide({duration: "slow", queue: false});
            });
        }
        else
            $(".tif-member-listing").show({duration: "fast", queue: false});
    });
}(jQuery));
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pfkjt6Lw/1/)

You can see that the speed is improved but still has lag. i think it couldn't be improved much more, because you are doing really lots of repeats in a wrong way.
You can see that categories with fewer items like "Events" run smoothly but about categories like "All Categories" you can see lots of lags and you don't have better choice than `$(".tif-member-listing").show({duration: "fast", queue: false});` if you persist on animation effect.

So i think if it's possible to change your HTML structure, do it. Put items of each category in a separate `div` and `show` and `hide` this divs on every change.
In this way you lost traffic in the first load (because some items are repeated in several categories), but earn much speed after load complete.

Comment: Thanks, yes, I will give them class names with those values, instead of using the `data-categories`.  Just thought of doing this to make it faster also.  Cheers :)

Comment: This doesn't help at all.  I still need to remove all of the old items, and some members can have multiple categories.

Comment: @SolomonClosson: i can't figure out your problem that mentioned in last comment, "I still need to remove all of the old items". Could you provide more details? maybe it be helpful for a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

One problem I can see here is the use animations to show/hide elements...

jQuery animations uses javascript based algorithm to produce the animation effect. Since in your case you have lot elements which has to be hidden/displayed the animation routine might take a while to complete which might be the reason for the slowness of the page.

So my suggestion will be is to remove the animation from show/hide, if you still want to use animation have a look at css3 animations(not an expert in css3 so don't really know how to go about it)... since it is native, should be faster(no guarantees)....

Comment: Thanks for your help Arun!  You are the best! +1 from me!